# How to get mouse position properly on keypress with autohotkey Invalid Hotkey Error

Tags: automation, autohotkey

***For those who find this later, for google reasons or anything, while the comments helped, I largely had to re-do the code from scratch. If you want the CSP equivalent of a private layer in Procreate, or if you want to use CSPs recording features without your reference layers showing up, download autohotkey and this script, then set the following settings.***

1. CTRL and Numpad+ to zoom in
2. CTRL and Numpad- to zoom out
3. Middle Mouse button to pan.

***Then do the following, put a reference of some sort on both pages, a large checkerboard, a dot with a few lines through it, whatever. Then line up both windows so that they're showing exactly same thing, only use middle mouse button to pan, and CTRL+ and CTRL- to zoom in and out.***

This is my first autohotkey script, and I'm trying to link up two different windows of an art program, so that when I pan one canvas, it pans the other. I would like it to be as pixel precise as possible, but I'm getting an error on Line 1 that says it's an invalid hotkey, I've tried removing the variables, and moving the commas around, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code. for purposes, I'll explain the button combinations.

Space + L Mouse Button together lets me pan the canvas, I need to know where the cursor is when I release one or the other.

LCtrl + Numpad5 disables click through on WindowTop which I use to overlay with transparency one window over the other.

LCtrl + Tab switches between the two canvasses in the app

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe CLIPStudioPaint.exe

; coordmode 
Coordmode, Mouse, Screen 
t := 0

;Below line starts script, and declares The Starting Coordinates

WinTitle = 3DLayer
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

^F9::
WinSet,Transparent, Off

^F11::
WinSet, ExStyle, -0x20, % WinTitle
return

^F10::
WinSet, ExStyle, +0x20, % WinTitle
WinSet, Transparent, 128, % WinTitle
return

~MButton::
 if (t = 0)
{
    MouseGetPos, MouseStartX, MouseStartY
    t := 1
}

return

~MButton up:: 

;When MButton is released, records mouse ending positions
    MouseGetpos, MouseEndX, MouseEndY
;Blocks input in case I move mouse or touch keyboard while it's running
    BlockInput, On
; switches canvas
    Send ^{TAB} 
; set window for click through
    WinTitle = 3DLayer
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
; Disables Click Through
    WinSet, ExStyle, -0x20, % WinTitle
        ; drag 
    MouseClickDrag, M, MouseStartX, MouseStartY, MouseEndX, MouseEndY
;Re-enables Click Through
    WinSet, ExStyle, +0x20, % WinTitle
    Winset, Transparent, 150, % WinTitle
;Turns inputs back on, so that I can resume using the art program
    Send ^{TAB}
    BlockInput, Off
    t := 0
return

~^NumpadAdd::
    BlockInput, On
; Get Mouse Position
    MouseGetPos, ScrollX, ScrollY

;Block input, then switch canvases
    
    Send ^{Tab}
sleep 50
; Disables Click Through
    WinSet, ExStyle, -0x20, % WinTitle
; Move Mouse where it needs to be then scroll
    MouseMove, ScrollX, ScrollY
    Send ^{NumpadAdd}
;Re-enables Click Through
    WinSet, ExStyle, +0x20, % WinTitle
    Winset, Transparent, 150, % WinTitle
;Turns inputs back on, so that I can resume using the art program
    Send ^{TAB}
    BlockInput, Off
return

~^NumpadSub::
    BlockInput, On
; Get Mouse Position
    MouseGetPos, ScrollX, ScrollY

;Block input, then switch canvases
    
    Send ^{Tab}
sleep 50
; Disables Click Through
    WinSet, ExStyle, -0x20, % WinTitle
; Move Mouse where it needs to be then scroll
    MouseMove, ScrollX, ScrollY
    Send ^{NumpadSub}
;Re-enables Click Through
    WinSet, ExStyle, +0x20, % WinTitle
    Winset, Transparent, 150, % WinTitle
;Turns inputs back on, so that I can resume using the art program
    Send ^{TAB}
    BlockInput, Off
return
```

Comment: I'll be honest and say that I really wouldn't be able to tell this was AHK if you didn't say so. This is that far off from being functional AHK code. Could you try to explain better what each line is supposed to do so maybe something can be done about correcting them. I wasn't really able tell what the script is supposed to do based off your description.

Comment: I have added comments to say what every line on the page will do

Comment: I agree with @0x464e's assessment of your code- a lot of the syntax you are using resembles non-AHK languages. Here are a few of the simpler changes you can make to fix it a bit: 1. use `:=` instead of `=` when you are trying to assign values to variables; 2. Single line comments in AHK start with `;` (like Python does), and not `//` (like Java, C++, etc use); 3. If you want to have AHK Send keystrokes to your computer, check out the [`Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command. Here is [The Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) for a quickstart to AHK

Comment: Thank you for linking me the tutorial, & help deciphering what I am reading, it says that I can use the = command in place of the := command, it's just a legacy function, it also says that when I press two keys simultaneously to send a command, I use the & symbol, finally it says I declare a variable by listing it out as theVariableName := variableValue. In the glossary it says I can assign a value to a variable for MouseGetPos in the way that I've done so. Could you point me to which specific parts are incorrect? I did miss that I needed to use a send command, but it's breaking before that.

Comment: I am aware of that @AHK_Questionnaire, that was just a quick fix for many of the bigger issues that I noticed since other commitments prevented me from giving a full answer at that time. I'll try giving it a shot tonight (time permitting) and tomorrow night if I can't finish it today

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the biggest changes I made was replacing

```
Space UP || LMButton UP::MouseGetPos MouseEndX, MouseEndY
```

with

```
while (GetKeyState("LButton", "P") and GetKeyState("Space", "P")) 
    sleep 50  
 
MouseGetPos MouseEndX, MouseEndY
```

(since you cannot have nested hotkeys)

---

I don't actually know if it works as intended since I do not have the software you are using, but feel free to lmk if something isn't working properly.

---

### Update 1:

In order to preserve a key's native function, we can use the `~` modifier.

From the relevant part of the [modifier section of the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols):

> When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked
> (hidden from the system).

In order to implement this, we can add the `~` key as a prefix to the hotkey, turning

```
Space & LButton::
```

into

```
~Space & LButton::
```

---

Current Code v2:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe CLIPStudioPaint.exe
;Below line starts script, and declares 4 variables with the value 0 to reset the script, to make sure for no reason it uses the old values
~Space & LButton::
;Once variables are declared, it records those variables
MouseGetPos MouseStartX, MouseStartY

;When space or Mouse button release, it uses the 4 recorded variables to move and click on the canvas

while (GetKeyState("LButton", "P") and GetKeyState("Space", "P")) 
    sleep 50  
 
MouseGetPos MouseEndX, MouseEndY

;Blocks input in case I move mouse or touch keyboard while it's running
BlockInput, On

;Disables Click Through in WindowTop (That's a literal name of the program) by pressing CTRL and Numpad5
Send ^{Numpad5}

;Switches Canvasses to the new canvas (Basically a 2nd tab in the program)
Send ^{TAB}

;Uses the recorded mouse positions to middle mouse button drag the exact same way I had in the previous section
MouseClickDrag, M, MouseStartX, MouseStartY, MouseEndX, MouseEndY

;Re-enables Click Through
Send ^{TAB}

;Switches back too original canvas
Send ^{Numpad5}

;Turns inputs back on, so that I can resume using the art program
BlockInput, Off

return
Space::Space
```

---

Comment: This is almost perfect, the only problem I'm having is that Space and Left Click are not remaining held when the macro activates, and so the program isn't reading that I'm dragging.

Comment: That should be an easy fix, if you want the keys in hotkey to retain their native function, and not to be blocked (hidden from the system), you can use the `~` modifier. I'll update the post and the code to include this